# How to enable Google Translate on text selection in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation

Android offers integration with Google Translate. You can get translation of selected text right from Google Translate in any app you're in currently:

1. Select a piece of text:

[image]

2. Get the translation:

[image]

But in iPhone, I only have **Look Up** option available in the context menu:

[image]

which opens dictionaries built into iOS. It is not bad, but it can't translate text.

[image]

Is it possible to integrate Android like Google Translate features into iPhone?

Comment: You can use Workflow.app to create a workflow and have it translate whatever is selected currently. There is a default action which uses Microsoft services, but using Google should work with a custom action as well. Will try to post an answer on this later.

Comment: @nohillside  Has the name changed to Shortcuts?  Some info for using the MS stuff is at https://www.cultofmac.com/591320/how-to-translate-anything-with-siri-shortcuts/

Comment: @TomGewecke Indeed it has :-) Great link, do you want to turn it into an answer?

Answer (score 2):

A workaround could be to download Apple's [Shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/welcome/ios) app from the app store and use it to invoke the MS translation service, as described in [this article](https://www.cultofmac.com/591320/how-to-translate-anything-with-siri-shortcuts/).

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to integrate Android like Google Translate features in iPhone?

No, it is not possible to integrate Google Translate feature in iPhone.

Instant translation feature is not built into iOS. If you need translation of a piece of text, you need to select it and translate it with the help of any of the translation services available via their web site or iOS app.

If you want to use Google Translate for your translation needs, you have two options in iOS:

- Install the [Google Translate iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/app/google-translate/id414706506)

or

- Access the [Google Translate homepage](https://translate.google.com) in the Web browser app of your choice.

---

If you would like to request Apple to integrate translation feature in iOS, you can do so here:

- [Feedback - iPhone](https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html)

Make sure to select **Feature Request** under **Feedback Type**.

Comment: Thanks for editing my questions, Nimesh :) 

Answer (score 0):

The ios shortcut that uses Microsoft translate works perfectly.  Select text, press share and send the text to the translate shortcut. Brilliant

Comment: What is ios shortcut that uses Microsoft translate? How to implement?